# Difference between "истина" and "правда"?

Tags: разница

Is there a way to describe the difference in meaning between инстина and правда? Is the difference more or less significant in colloquial speech, in comparison to more formal or legal writing? I often see правда translated to 'true' in the sense of 'really,' which seems softer or at least without the ontological weight that истина has as 'a truth.'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

["Истина"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) is of a higher register, is more pathetic (in its archaic sense of "full of pathos." As was kindly pointed out to me in comments, "pompous" might be a better term) if you will (or just strict - when one is talking about Boolean operations, it's about "истина" and "ложь", not about "правда" and "неправда"). It's something unarguably true, almost axiomatic. In another meaning, "истина" stands for something authentic, like in "истинные патриоты" ("правдивые патриоты" meaning those who don't lie). So in colloquial speech, they are not interchangeable in the overwhelming majority of cases, not to mention that one will hardly ever hear "истина" in colloquial speech.

You just cannot say "я тебе истину говорю, я встречался с друзьями".

If you want to delve deeper and grasp the difference on an ontological level, [this article](https://ru.readkong.com/page/koncepty-pravda-i-istina-v-russkoy-kulturnoy-6115039?p=1) may be a good starting point. There are some nice examples of the use of "правда" and "истина" as quasi-synonyms cited in that article.

Comment: "is more _pathetic_ if you will" - please be careful with this word in English. 
I would rather use "lofty".

Comment: @Alexander why?

Comment: [Pathetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathetic) "1 .having a capacity to move one to either compassionate or contemptuous **pity**"

Comment: Pathetic в разговорном английском одназначно означает "жалкий". Патетический в значении "пафосный", "напыщеный" - это скорее pretentious или pompous.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что слово "истина" жалкое и примитивное?

Comment: yes you can. you may think you may not, but you certainly can, that is not degraded language in any way.

Comment: `я тебе истину говорю, я встречался с друзьями.` I think it's fine to say that.

Comment: @user7808407 fine but intentionally in a higher register

Answer (score 5):

From my perspective `истина` is an idea that came from the Bible and in meaning is very close to objective reality. Although the very word `objective` is superfluous since the opposite of reality is falsehood, that is a lie. `Истина`, I think, can also be understood as `Being`. With `non-Being` being an opposite.

`Правда` is related with law as in Latin `juris` (право). A `righteous` (праведный) person in the Bible is someone who succeeds in following the God’s law. Hence `правда` is about truthful (!) reflection of a mere fact.

I feel that most people in Russia though wouldn't be able to explain this difference. When they start thinking about the diffence, they can’t define it. I suspect it’s the same in any country and all languages =) They are using these words intuitively and in my opinion according to the explanation I’ve given above. Sometimes these things are getting confused hence an odd idea that `правда` is a very special word that can’t be translated into other languages. When someone says `это правда` (this is true (!)) he states that he is not lying in his account of phenomena, and he would never say that what he is saying is `истина` (noumena).

In mathematics or programming a word `истина` is used because math is about absolute truths (!). So `истина` is absolute and `правда` is relative. There is a word `правдоруб` (from `правда` and `рубить` (to axe)). It is used to describe someone who operates facts to hurt people, using law as an axe, not caring about other’s feelings or about `истина` (the truth (!)). The most important thing for such a man is to be `right` by all costs.

To conclude I’ll quote [a Wikipedia article on truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth):

> All Germanic languages besides English have introduced a terminological distinction between truth "fidelity" and truth "factuality".

So, basically, `истина` is ‘fidelity’ and `правда` is ‘factuality’.

As I am from the continent it’s hard for me to imagine what’s happening in minds of English-speaking people and if there is such a distinction in English, and if there is how to express it in English.

Comment: It is interesting to look at this from religious aspect, and then expand to everyday usage. And I agree that истина is for universal "truths" while правда can be different for different people.

Answer (score 2):

Правда - это справедливость, правота, правосудие.

> И'стина ж. противоположность лжи; все, что вuрно, подлинно, **точно**,
>   справедливо, что есть**); нынu слову этому отвuчаетъ и правда, хотя
>   вuрнuе будетъ понимать подъ словомъ правда: правди'вость,
>   справедливость, правосудiе, правота.
>   Даль

Для русских правда - только одна (не может быть "много правд"). Ситуация описывающаяся поговоркой "у каждого своя правда" - или говорит о запутанности ситуации (спора) или о том, что тема - частная, принципиально не важная.

> "Тоталитарные комплексы — распространенная патология психики,
>   состоящая в систематической переоценке субъективного переживания
>   полезности какой-либо вещи или услуги по сравнению с ее рыночной
>   ценой. Так, систематическая переоценка ценности достоверной информации
>   приводит к "комплексу правдивости" или "правдоискательству";
>   переоценка ценности дизайна предмета по отношению к его
>   пользовательским характеристикам приводит к "эстетизму" или "культу
>   красоты" и т.п. К тоталитарным комплексам относится также
>   моносексуальность (направленность сексуального влечения только на один
>   объект, "влюбленность"). Особым видом тоталитарного комплекса
>   считается иррациональное сопротивление законам рынка. Характерен для
>   русских".
>   Константин Крылов "Новый мировой порядок. Тезаурус"

Есть моральная (этическая) сторона, суждение, оценка - значит правда.
Пример: "правда глаза колет" (пословица о проявлении стыда или совести).

Истина - это фактически точное (верное) утверждение из логики, соответствие букве закона.
Бывают "прописные истины", "азбучные истины" (сравните с правдой, которая почти не имеет устойчивых словосочетаний с множественным числом).

> Настоящая правда всегда неправдоподобна; чтобы сделать её
>   правдоподобнее, нужно примешать к ней лжи
>    (Достоевский).

Правда - нравственная категория, дух закона.

*«Истина от земли, а правда с небес»*
Правда - это ... *«Соответствие факта истине при соблюдении законов чести»*

> Вот скажи мне, американец, в чём сила? Разве в деньгах? Вот и брат
>   говорит, что в деньгах. У тебя много денег, и чего? Я вот думаю, что
>   **сила в правде**. У кого правда — тот и сильней. Вот ты обманул кого-то,
>   денег нажил. И чего, ты сильнее стал? Нет, не стал. Потому что правды
>   за тобой нет. А тот, кого обманул, за ним правда, значит, он сильней.
>   Да?
>
> Идея справедливости была и остается одной из «ключевых идей русской
>   языковой картины мира» (см.: Зализняк-Левонтина 2005: 11), жажда
>   безусловной справедливости, «которая должна осуществляться в жизни
>   вопреки царствующей в ней неправде» (Трубецкой 1994: 280) –
>   «стержневой линией духовных исканий, стремлений русского человека»
>   (Рачков 1996: 15), а правда воспринимается как фундаментальная основа
>   жизни, на которой строится вся русская духовная культура (см.:
>   Бобылева 2007: 9). Стремление к справедливости составляет один из
>   наиболее значимых автостереотипов нации: «Чем мы, россияне, отличаемся
>   от других? Для нас важно, чтоб было СПРАВЕДЛИВО» (АиФ 2006, № 38);
>   «Для русского человека несчастье – не просто бедность, нехватка денег,
>   а нарушение справедливости, триумф людей без стыда» (АиФ 2004, № 44).
>   Считается, что в русской культуре существует «особое чувство – любовь
>   к справедливости» (Левонтина-Шмелев 2000: 284), а «жажда правды»
>   составляет специфику «русского национального духа» (см.: Юлдашев 2008:
>   15–16). По утверждению Ф. М. Достоевского, «высшая и самая характерная
>   черта нашего народа – это чувство справедливости и жажда её», можно
>   сказать, нас «мучит справедливости мираж» (Губерман). Как и всякая
>   любовь, любовь к справедливости может составить смысл и счастье жизни:
>   «Самое главное условие, которое нужно человеку для счастья, – ощущение
>   смысла, что “понапрасну ни зло ни добро не пропало”» (АиФ 2006: № 49);
>   «Сказано в Писании: “Правды ищи, дабы ты был жив”. Для всех нас это
>   значит – живи так, чтоб знал ты, как придать смысл своей жизни!» (АиФ
>   2003, № 45). Справедливость для русского человека выше истины («А для
>   русской души справедливость выше правды» – АиФ 2006, № 51) и дороже
>   жизни («За правду надо стоять или висеть на кресте» – Пришвин; «Чем в
>   кривде мотаться, лучше за правду умереть» – Артем Веселый). По
>   утверждению Ивана Ильина, «Россия есть прежде всего – живой сонм
>   русских правдолюбцев, “прямых стоятелей”, верных Божьей правде» (Ильин
>   2007: 7). Можно добавить, что не только «стоятелей», но и «сидельцев»
>   и страдальцев за правду.
>
> С высокой степенью вероятности опознается «гносеологическое» значение
>   «правды» в контексте лексики речи, знания, откровения, заблуждения,
>   обличения: «И чувства нет в твоих очах, / И правды нет в твоих речах,
>   / И нет души в тебе» (Тютчев); «И новая правда звучала / На древних
>   твоих языках» (Ахматова); «Нет, правды не оспаривай» (Цветаева); «Я
>   знаю правду! Все прежние правды – прочь!» (Цветаева); «Все тут, да тут
>   и человек и свет, / И смерть, и жизнь, и правда без покрова»
>   (Баратынский); «Ты видел правду, / Но правду снов… Ищи живую правду»
>   (Луговской); «Горькой правдой всю душу вытомив, / я на ложь не оставил
>   сил» (Дементьев); «Бежать? Куда? Где правда, где ошибка? (Фет); «Боже,
>   сколько правды в глазах государственных шлюх! (Шевчук);
>
> «Бежал из тюрьмы темной ночью, / В тюрьме он за правду страдал»
>   (Песня).

слово

> «правда», в котором истина и справедливость «как бы сливаются в одно
>   великое целое» (см.: Печенев 1990: 140) и которое «оказывается как бы
>   мостом, соединяющим истину с моралью» (Знаков 1999, 147)

Цитаты по https://gigabaza.ru/doc/53218-pall.html [С. Г. ВОРКАЧЕВ Правды ищи: идея справедливости в русской лингвокультуре. Монография. 
Волгоград, «Парадигма», 2009](https://gigabaza.ru/doc/53218-pall.html)

Answer (score 1):

The devil is in the detail with the best contextual translation of "truth", "the truth", "correctness", "realness", "is it real?" and other phrases that convey a strong correspondence with reality or the way things actually are.

Правда has some baggage as a word, being associated with the Правда Communist-era Newspaper (that is still going today).

And правда is used very commonly in general day-to-day discussions to validate the truthfulness of a statement. Often it appears when the person hearing the fact is a little surprised, or doubtful. Below is an example of gossip between two friends about two people who have started a relationship.

One Friend: слышали, что Маша встречается с Сергеем?
  Other Friend: правда ... я не знала.

правда can also be used to express simple agreement with a statement.

Я ищу правду

Is "I'm looking for the truth" or "I'm trying to find to find out what happened" but likely in context to a concrete event or question.

Я ищу истину

Is a bit more high-level, you are searching for "the truth" in a big picture way.

Comment: Cleaned this up. Would welcome the input of a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Истина (axiomatic truth) is the ultimate truth. It has a spiritual law of every human. 6 million years of evolution of our feelings, emotions and thoughts gives us unique way to perceive the world. Истина is “everything”, interconnected and balanced like nature. Truth(правда) is or could be a part of “истина”, it has different perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

- Истина - is an objective fact that is true.
- Правда -  is a subjective message (spoken or written) that is considered to be true.

Правда may be not истина, when person spoken  (or listening) belives in some false facts.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It does not work like this: if I am not sure of what I say I may just change the word "истина" for "правда", and all is okay. No, both words translate the word "the truth" in a perfectly correct way, and by default all truth is objective.

Comment: @Evgeniy, the no "default" truthfulness. Philosophers were and are discussing objectivness of truth for thousands of years and did not come to any conclusion. And this forum is not about philosophy (they had their own forum). This exactly question is about *semantics*. And when I say "истина" I refere to smth, that should be (by my opinion) considered an objective truth. When I say "правда", I refer to some text (in written or spoken form), I consider to be true. In English both are "truth", but in Russian there is a difference.

Comment: nonsense, sorry

Answer (score -1):

В английском слове "the truth" есть два аспекта. Они отражены двумя разными словами русского языка.
Истина — то, что есть на самом деле. Корень слова — "тот самый", "настоящий".
Правда — то, как правильно думать и делать.
Оба слова используются в самых разных регистрах.
По умолчанию лучше использовать слово "правда".

Эти значения накладываются на разные реалии русского языка и порождают огромное количество разных примеров. Приводить их все было излишне — наверное, ответ на ваш вопрос может занять целую книгу. Приведу вот какой: "истинная дочь" — это та, которая дочь на самом деле, а не только на словах. А "праведная дочь" — это дочь, которая делает всё правильно, всё как подобает. Это словосочетание может появиться только в высоком регистре. Немножко похожее слово "правдивая дочь" — это дочь, которая говорит всегда правду… То есть говорит то, что и надо думать об обсуждаемом предмете (англ. the truth).

PS: дополнительные примеры здесь - https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30249/

Comment: Если кто-то считает нужным перевести ответ на английский — я считаю, что оригинал надо оставить на месте, потому что он в любом случае точнее. Задан вопрос о довольно тонком месте в русской лексике, которое имеет значение для многих людей. По-настоящему тонкие вопросы языка имеет смысл обсуждать на самом языке, потому что слова мы объясняем при помощи слов, и при переходе на другой язык системность объяснения теряется, теряется и смысл.

Comment: Перевод - у меня в ответе. Причём максимально по существу, без воды. И не надо путать иностранцев используя "корень слова" не в орфографическом смысле ("истина" и "настоящий" разнокоренные и разногнездовые слова) (UPD: минус - не от меня)

Comment: @ksbes Ну, если вы не умеете отличать существенное от несущественного… Тогда да; а так — нет.

Answer (score -2):

Really - no difference.

Those who believe that there is a semantic difference are usually demagogues who want to level the difference between truth and falsehood :)

Ok, "Истина" may be more pathos for someone, but in reality, since there is no difference between them, I don't recognize this connotation:>

Comment: Ultimately, the meanings are pretty much the same. But it's just how the words get used in terms of common and established phrases.